# JavaScript / Jquery call controller synchroneousely

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to synchronously call a controller (url) in my Javascript. I could do this with an Ajax function like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: BASE + '/publication/storeWorldCat',
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false
});
```

I don't understand why I should use an Ajax function with a `async:false` parameter as Ajax is asynchronous by definition. `$post()` is asynchronous too.

Is there a better way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand why you would use a synchronous ajax call either ?

Comment: So basically you would like a function `$.jax()`, that would have `async` set to false by default? ...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [**the documentation of `jQuery.ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) *(quoting*) :

> **By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously** *(i.e. this is set to
>   `true` by default)*. If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option
>   to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Granted, [AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript and XML](https://web.archive.org/web/20080704132149/http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/essays/archives/000385.php) so any request sent in Javascript that is not sent asynchronously or does not use XML as the data format should technically not be called an AJAX request. With the popularity of JSON nowadays, it looks like the `$.ajax` function is *REALLY* badly named since it allows any data format.

But many other acronyms are chosen to be easy to pronounce at the cost of not being totally correct, and I think we can live with it. So to answer your questions:

Why has the jQuery team decided to name this function `ajax`? Because this acronym was already used by everyone, regardless of the data format used and the "synchronousness". Why is everyone using this acronym wrongly? Probably because it did not make sense to make a new acronym for each data format, each time with an optional 'A' for whether it is asynchronous.

*Why [you] should use an Ajax function with a `async:false` parameter as Ajax is asynchronous by definition?*

Well, you don't have to:

```
$.sendRequest = $.ajax
```

And now you can use a function with a better name in your code. You can even change the default behaviour:

```
$.sendRequest = function(options) {
  if (typeof options.async === undefined) {
    options.async = false;
  }
  $.ajax.apply($, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer! I now understand better :-) Very appreciated!